# Perspective Shell: match instances full hostname

Tags: cloud, openstack, perspective-shell

All virtual machines in my cloud have the following hostname pattern: `<vm_name>.example.com`, where `vm_name` is virtual machine name and `example.com` is some fixed domain name. Is there any way to match not only against VM name but also consider full hostname, e.g.:

```
perspective> show instances --name vm-one,vm-two
perspective> show instances --name vm-one.example.com,vm-two.example.com # I would like this!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify all available domain zones (so called "instance suffixes") in your **~/.perspective/rc** file as follows:

```
set instance_suffixes = .example.com,.test.net
```

Then just search for instances as usually:

```
perspective> show instances --name vm-one.example.com,vm-two.test.net
```